# Storage an Object as Class to file

Tags: swift, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

I have some classes: A, B, C with descriptions:

```
class A {
    var index: int = 0
    init(){}
}

class B {
    var a1 : A?
    var a2 : A?
    var relation : int?

    init(){}
}

class C {
    var vA : [A] = []
    var vB : [B] = []

    int(){
    }
}
```

//In main program, set data for C by

```
var c : C = C()

let a1 : A = A()
a1. index = 1
let a2 : A = A()
a2.index = 2

let b : B = B()
b.a1 = a1
b.a2 = a2
b.releation = 1

c.vA.append(a1)
c.vA.append(a2)

c.vB.append(b)
```

And now I want to store the data of 'c' to file, and will get back again from this file in next time. What's solution for that? Write and Read file or any suggestion !

I try with  **NSKeyedArchiver** to archive data and **NSKeyedUnArchiver** to unarchive data again, but, when check file always '**File not found**', and **'ALWAYS return NIL'**

```
            var c1 = c
            let dataArchive : Data = Data(bytes: &c1, count: MemoryLayout<C>.stride)

let randomFilename = UUID().uuidString
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: dataArchive)
            let fullPath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(randomFilename)

            do {
              try data.write(to: fullPath)
            } catch {
                print("Couldn't write file")
            }

            let filemgr = FileManager.default
            if filemgr.fileExists(atPath: fullPath.absoluteString) {
                print("File exists")
            } else {
                print("File not found")
            }
//
     var dataArchiveLoaded : Data?
     let x = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: fullPath.absoluteString)
      print(x)  //ALWAYS return NIL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using Swift 4, you could always make your class files conform to `Codable` when that’s done, you can just use the `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` to encode and decode the object respectively. The encoded data can then be saved to a file. If you’d prefer to see some code let me know :)

Comment: JSONEncoder JSONDecoder is suitable for complex data types like the above class?

Comment: @TuanHuynh Yup, as long as all properties conform to `Codable` you should be good :)